Is it ok to run a ros2 program without 'ros2 run'?
We run some of our ROS2 nodes without using the prefix of ros2 run.
Is this a problem for ros nodes, maybe now or in the future?
If ros2 run is required, what functions does it perform?
Thank you!

You can definitely run your ROS 2 executables without ros 2 run. But then you need to specify the path to the executable. With ros 2 run, you just need to specify the ROS 2 package name:
ros2 run <package_name> <executable_name>

As long as you have sourced your ROS workspace (e.g. with source install/setup.bash), you can run ros2 run ... from whatever directory your terminal may be located in.
